# How to setup onDidReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

For iOS setup of flutter_local_notifications, it need to add the onDidReceiveLocalNotification for IOSInitializationSettings, but the example code is not out of box, how to fix it correctly?

```
void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
    int id, String title, String body, String payload) async { // How to pass id, title, body and payload
  showDialog(
    context: context, // How to get the context of dialog?
    builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(body),
      actions: [
        CupertinoDialogAction(
          isDefaultAction: true,
          child: Text('Ok'),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```